# Handling multiple keydown events on same key one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my project i have multiple events binded on window escape keydown pressing , and all of them are executed at the same time when escape key is pressed.

I need to make this events to fire only one escape key press at a time, in a particular order, how can i do this?

It needs to works similarly as in telegram web version when pressing escape to deselect messages and then press again to close chat with someone.

Comment: Either unbind the original event using `off()` before adding the new one, or place the functions to be run in order in an array and iterate through that. If you need more specific help, please add your current code to the question.

Comment: In telegram case it looks like it depends on the state. If there are selected messages, then deselect, else - close.